# Upload multiple ssh keys to a vps

Tags: linux, ssh, vps, ssh-keys

Internet documentation about securing a vps suggests to Disable SSH password authentication and use instead a cryptographic key-pair authentication. See for instance [Linode's documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/securing-your-server#harden-ssh-access).

I wonder what happens in case the computer whose public key I uploaded to my server stops working and I have to switch to another computer: this is the worst scenario.

However, I may simply want to change my old computer with a new one. Or I may be tempted to resize my hdd and install the next LTS Ubuntu version alongside the previous one and move all my data instead of trying a risky upgrade: my new OS would generate/have a different ssh key, though.

What can I do to avoid to be locked out from my server? 
To my understanding, once SSH password authentication is disabled and a public key is uploaded to the server, it is possible to ssh connect to the server only using that key. Nevertheless I wonder: is there any way to upload more than one public key? If this is possible, the server would accept connections from more than one computer via authentication through different public keys (although I do not see how the second computer can ssh connect to upload its key).

Is the alternative of making a backup of my `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files practicable?

Comment: I think you could use the keys from a virtual machine instead. In the case of you box dying etc you could then setup the vm on another host and still access the remote computer from this virtual machine.

Comment: I see, you are suggesting to make backups of the virtual machine and eventually copy it to the new host?

Comment: Yes, if you would like to use it on another machine later on. The vm could be created from a very small linux distribution like for instance knoppix or similar. Notice that I'm not sure that this will work but it may be worth a try.

Comment: IMO it is overkill to have a full copy of virtual machine instead of just keeping a copy of the private key.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov - You would use a vm If the actual computer goes down or gets stolen. You could for instance use a damn-small linux image which is only ca 50mb - https://virtualboxes.org/images/damn-small/

Comment: @Cyclonecode ok, but then you'll have to run this VM somewhere on a physical machine, where you can simply use an SSH client and a backup of a private key without having to set up your VM.

Comment: @OlegAndriyanov - Thats true =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many keys to `sshd` on your VPS as you want:

- generate one with `ssh-keygen` and save somewhere
- copy public part (with sufix `.pub`) of the generated key to your server
- add this public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (or the one specified in the `AuthorizedKeysFile` entry in `sshd_config`): `cat key.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- reload sshd (on my Ubuntu it goes like `sudo service ssh reload`)
- connect using the new key: `ssh -i /path/to/private-key host@user`

Comment: Is the third point to be performed in my local machine or in the server? If I am not wrong, this procedure would create a new ssh key in the _same_ machine and _same_ OS.

Comment: @Asarluhi yes, points 3 and 4 are to be run on the server. Basically, point 3 configures `sshd` to trust any client who owns the key you are adding, and point 4 just tells `sshd` to use the new configuration.

Comment: If point 2 is accomplished using `ssh-copy-id`, this command should automatically edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (point 3 is still necessary?) and also probably it might overwrite the previous key. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Asarluhi Actually, almost the whole procedure can be done with `ssh-copy-id`, but I've never used it. All editing of `authorized_keys` boils down to appending a new key to the file, which is done with operator `>>`. Note that it won't overwrite anything unline `>`, it just appends (or creates and appends).

Comment: Ok, I got it now. To sum up you suggest to generate the new key from the authorized computer, add it to the server, then (implicit) copy it to the second computer. Thanks, great solution.